# Prove uniqueness of $\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x,t)$ with smooth v

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on Arnold's book on ODEs and stumbled across this problem of proving the uniqueness of the solution $\phi(t)$ fulfilling $\phi(t_0)=x_0$ for the ODE $\frac{dx}{dt}=v(x,t)$ with smooth v. 
He gives the hint that if one substitutes $x:=x-\phi(t)$, the right-hand-side vanishes and one can compare the resulting directional field with a linear field, but I don't understand the first step. If I substitute I get $\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}=v(x-\phi(t),t)$. How is the right-hand-side supposed to disappear?
P.S.: In case, somebody wants to look up the exact exercise, it's on page 38 Exercise No. 5:
https://de.slideshare.net/contrerasmunive1/ordinary-differential-equations-arnold

Comment: I‘m stumbled too.